# Generate executable file at runtime - C++ / Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, runtime

Maybe you can help me with a question I have, related to C++ language:

Is it possible or, is there a way to generate an executable file at runtime of a C++ Windows application?

To illustrate you why I'm asking this, I will detail the scenario that I'm thinking right now:

I have a C++ Windows Application that is more like an editor, where the user inputs some data and make some configurations, so when everything is done, the user clicks the "Run" button and this editor based on the user input data and configurations, creates some C++ or C# code files,  compiles them and generates an executable file that the user can simply use without having to enter any line of code by himself.

Is it possible? Please can you give me a clue of how to do my search or where to find some help?

Comment: One obvious solution is to just run the Visual C++ compiler from your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is possible, the compiler itself is likely a program that fulfils this requirement.

If you want to do it without just invoking a compiler though (and thus generate source code to feed it), you need to learn quite a bit about the machine language and executable file format of your platform.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply make a call from your application to an external compiler, make the compiler build your executable and if the compilation is successful you could run the resulting executable. You can even capture the output of the compiler in your application.